# Recursive model binding failure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

The model binder is failing to instantiate a sub-object in my action argument - `PublicationSchedule` is always null, `Id`, `Name`, `Region` are populated OK. Can anyone suggest why this might be?

The action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(ProductTemplateViewModel viewModel)
{
    //...
}
```

The models to bind to:

```
public class ProductTemplateViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Region { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public PublicationScheduleViewModel PublicationSchedule { get; set; }
}

public class PublicationScheduleViewModel
{
    [Required, StringArrayNotEmpty]
    public string[] DaysOfWeek { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(0, 23)]
    public int HoursOfDay { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(0, 59)]
    public int MinutesOfHour { get; set; }
}
```

HTTP request form data:

```
id:gf
name:fg
region:Africa
daysOfWeek:Wednesday
hoursOfDay:3
minutesOfHour:4
```

The form:

```
<input type="text" id="id" name="id">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<select id="region" name="region">
    <option value="Africa" selected="selected">Africa</option>
</select>       
<input type="checkbox" id="chk(Monday)" name="daysOfWeek" value="Monday">
<input type="checkbox" id="chk(Tuesday)" name="daysOfWeek" value="Tuesday">
<select id="hoursOfDay" name="hoursOfDay">
        <option value="0">00</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>                       
</select>
<select id="minutesOfHour" name="minutesOfHour">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">00</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>                       
</select>
```

Comment: What is in your form? Please paste that here.

Comment: Can you post your actual view code which contains the form? Or you directly "hardcoded" all the HTML? Why don't you use the strongly typed view and the built in HTML.helpers? And by the way the model binder supports complex nested viewmodels (and the built in HTML.helpers supports this and generates the right HTML) you just need to name your inputs accordingly: e.g.: `daysOfWeek` should be `PublicationSchedule.daysOfWeek` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field names need to be 
PublicationSchedule.daysOfWeek, PublicationSchedule.hoursOfDay, and PublicationSchedule.minutesOfHour